# Geojson fails to render correctly

Tags: geojson, geojsonio

Am trying to create a geojson map of a community forest. I created this geojson file by hand and it loads correctly in QGIS but doesn't work on geojson.io

Could anyone spot what I am doing wrong.

[Sample GeoJson file](https://gist.github.com/arky/539080e5a4a18c7b4bde6792d8fabe3c)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `crs` reference and try again, either at geojson.io or http://geojsonlint.com/ or https://kepler.gl/demo.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"final","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"shape":"Polygon","maps":"(1:default-map)","name":"Unnamed Layer","category":"default","id":"cd2df240-47e6-4b56-8250-8d2f4ccc1e72"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[7.78,99.0632],[7.7815,99.0627],[7.7816,99.0627],[7.7824,99.0625],[7.7828,99.0624],[7.7831,99.0623],[7.7832,99.0622],[7.7834,99.062],[7.7838,99.0614],[7.7839,99.0614],[7.784,99.0613],[7.7843,99.0611],[7.7876,99.0592],[7.7895,99.0578],[7.7893,99.0575],[7.7891,99.0574],[7.7883,99.0568],[7.7868,99.056],[7.7867,99.0559],[7.786,99.0557],[7.7854,99.0556],[7.7844,99.0554],[7.784,99.0552],[7.7837,99.055],[7.7834,99.0546],[7.7831,99.0544],[7.7826,99.0541],[7.7819,99.0537],[7.7816,99.0543],[7.7816,99.0545],[7.7796,99.053],[7.7802,99.052],[7.7795,99.0516],[7.7791,99.0514],[7.7786,99.0511],[7.7779,99.0505],[7.7771,99.0499],[7.7763,99.0492],[7.7761,99.049],[7.7758,99.0488],[7.7758,99.0488],[7.7755,99.0488],[7.7752,99.0489],[7.775,99.0493],[7.7748,99.0497],[7.7747,99.0498],[7.7746,99.05],[7.7743,99.0502],[7.7743,99.0502],[7.7739,99.0505],[7.7738,99.0506],[7.7737,99.0507],[7.7734,99.0514],[7.7723,99.0523],[7.7722,99.0523],[7.7721,99.0524],[7.772,99.0524],[7.7716,99.0524],[7.7713,99.0524],[7.7709,99.0523],[7.7703,99.0521],[7.7701,99.052],[7.7699,99.0519],[7.7696,99.0519],[7.7696,99.0519],[7.7695,99.0519],[7.7694,99.0519],[7.7692,99.052],[7.7691,99.052],[7.7687,99.0523],[7.7687,99.0523],[7.7685,99.0523],[7.7679,99.0523],[7.7678,99.0523],[7.7678,99.0513],[7.7682,99.0509],[7.7684,99.0508],[7.7686,99.0507],[7.7689,99.0506],[7.7691,99.0506],[7.7692,99.0506],[7.7693,99.0506],[7.7694,99.0504],[7.7695,99.0502],[7.7695,99.0502],[7.7696,99.0501],[7.7697,99.05],[7.77,99.0499],[7.7705,99.0498],[7.7708,99.0496],[7.771,99.0495],[7.771,99.0494],[7.7711,99.0494],[7.7712,99.0493],[7.7713,99.0493],[7.7715,99.0492],[7.7718,99.0492],[7.772,99.0492],[7.7722,99.049],[7.7723,99.0488],[7.7726,99.0483],[7.7727,99.048],[7.7727,99.0478],[7.7728,99.0475],[7.7728,99.0471],[7.7729,99.0471],[7.7731,99.0469],[7.7735,99.0467],[7.7738,99.0466],[7.7743,99.0464],[7.7743,99.0458],[7.7743,99.0456],[7.7743,99.0454],[7.7744,99.0453],[7.7747,99.0449],[7.7753,99.0441],[7.7755,99.0438],[7.7756,99.0437],[7.7756,99.0434],[7.7757,99.043],[7.7758,99.0425],[7.776,99.0419],[7.7763,99.0419],[7.7766,99.0418],[7.7767,99.0417],[7.7769,99.0416],[7.7772,99.0409],[7.7775,99.0402],[7.7776,99.04],[7.7776,99.04],[7.7777,99.0399],[7.7777,99.0399],[7.7777,99.0399],[7.7778,99.0399],[7.7778,99.0398],[7.7783,99.0398],[7.7783,99.0391],[7.7783,99.0384],[7.7783,99.0379],[7.7783,99.0376],[7.7786,99.037],[7.7792,99.0358],[7.7795,99.0357],[7.7795,99.0357],[7.7797,99.0356],[7.7799,99.0355],[7.7801,99.0354],[7.7802,99.0352],[7.7804,99.035],[7.7805,99.0348],[7.7805,99.0347],[7.7805,99.0346],[7.7805,99.034],[7.7806,99.0332],[7.7807,99.0326],[7.7808,99.032],[7.7809,99.0317],[7.7809,99.0317],[7.781,99.0316],[7.7811,99.0314],[7.7811,99.0313],[7.7812,99.0311],[7.7813,99.0309],[7.7814,99.0309],[7.782,99.0303],[7.7818,99.0299],[7.7817,99.0295],[7.7815,99.0288],[7.7811,99.0272],[7.7784,99.0278],[7.7793,99.0285],[7.7785,99.0291],[7.7782,99.0293],[7.778,99.0295],[7.7778,99.0299],[7.7776,99.0301],[7.7768,99.0299],[7.7766,99.0299],[7.7764,99.03],[7.7763,99.0302],[7.7762,99.0308],[7.776,99.0313],[7.7759,99.0315],[7.7756,99.0318],[7.7741,99.0308],[7.7739,99.0306],[7.7736,99.0295],[7.7734,99.0293],[7.773,99.0292],[7.7723,99.0292],[7.7717,99.0288],[7.7715,99.0287],[7.7711,99.0286],[7.7709,99.0286],[7.7692,99.0277],[7.7684,99.0284],[7.7677,99.0285],[7.7674,99.0267],[7.7673,99.0266],[7.7645,99.0244],[7.7638,99.028],[7.763,99.0292],[7.7628,99.0294],[7.7625,99.0294],[7.7623,99.0293],[7.7621,99.0294],[7.7618,99.0296],[7.7617,99.0299],[7.7608,99.0295],[7.7605,99.0295],[7.758,99.0298],[7.7573,99.0304],[7.7571,99.0305],[7.7553,99.0306],[7.7535,99.0293],[7.7532,99.0229],[7.7525,99.0224],[7.7523,99.0223],[7.7484,99.0232],[7.7481,99.0233],[7.7466,99.0241],[7.7463,99.0242],[7.7461,99.0242],[7.7406,99.0252],[7.7382,99.0263],[7.7368,99.0268],[7.7365,99.0269],[7.7337,99.0285],[7.7281,99.031],[7.7275,99.0313],[7.7273,99.0315],[7.726,99.0324],[7.7258,99.0325],[7.7255,99.0325],[7.7218,99.0331],[7.7215,99.0332],[7.7181,99.0348],[7.714,99.0366],[7.7136,99.0367],[7.7123,99.0369],[7.711,99.0371],[7.7099,99.0373],[7.7093,99.0376],[7.7079,99.0383],[7.7065,99.039],[7.7055,99.0394],[7.704,99.0397],[7.7036,99.0399],[7.703,99.0403],[7.7023,99.0407],[7.7014,99.0411],[7.7007,99.0413],[7.7003,99.0415],[7.7001,99.0416],[7.6999,99.0419],[7.6997,99.0423],[7.6997,99.0427],[7.6999,99.0432],[7.6999,99.0436],[7.6999,99.0443],[7.6997,99.0453],[7.6996,99.0459],[7.6993,99.0464],[7.699,99.047],[7.6987,99.0481],[7.6984,99.0498],[7.6981,99.0531],[7.6977,99.0556],[7.6975,99.0566],[7.6975,99.057],[7.6975,99.0608],[7.697,99.0639],[7.697,99.0641],[7.6969,99.0642],[7.6955,99.0662],[7.6953,99.0664],[7.6951,99.0675],[7.695,99.0678],[7.695,99.0679],[7.6952,99.068],[7.6956,99.0681],[7.6958,99.0682],[7.6959,99.0684],[7.6958,99.0686],[7.6955,99.0688],[7.6952,99.0691],[7.695,99.0695],[7.6944,99.071],[7.6937,99.0736],[7.693,99.0768],[7.693,99.0773],[7.6932,99.0785],[7.6931,99.0786],[7.6929,99.0787],[7.692,99.0792],[7.6919,99.0793],[7.6919,99.0795],[7.6919,99.0798],[7.692,99.081],[7.6921,99.0814],[7.692,99.0816],[7.6919,99.0818],[7.6912,99.0827],[7.691,99.0829],[7.6909,99.0831],[7.6909,99.0834],[7.691,99.0847],[7.6909,99.0851],[7.6907,99.0857],[7.6906,99.0861],[7.6906,99.0864],[7.6908,99.0875],[7.6907,99.0882],[7.6905,99.0898],[7.6902,99.091],[7.69,99.0918],[7.6901,99.0921],[7.6901,99.0923],[7.6903,99.0925],[7.6904,99.0928],[7.6916,99.0959],[7.6918,99.0961],[7.6919,99.0963],[7.6922,99.0966],[7.6924,99.0969],[7.693,99.0979],[7.6933,99.0981],[7.6935,99.0982],[7.6937,99.0981],[7.6939,99.098],[7.6946,99.0972],[7.6951,99.0965],[7.6954,99.0956],[7.6955,99.0954],[7.6958,99.0952],[7.6961,99.0949],[7.6959,99.0939],[7.6955,99.0925],[7.6961,99.0913],[7.6966,99.09],[7.6967,99.0897],[7.6968,99.0896],[7.6971,99.0893],[7.6973,99.0889],[7.6982,99.0877],[7.6984,99.0875],[7.6994,99.0869],[7.6996,99.0865],[7.6998,99.0857],[7.7,99.0855],[7.7002,99.0854],[7.7006,99.0853],[7.7006,99.0848],[7.7007,99.0847],[7.7009,99.0847],[7.7014,99.0847],[7.7015,99.084],[7.7009,99.0838],[7.7008,99.0838],[7.7002,99.0844],[7.7,99.0844],[7.6997,99.0844],[7.6984,99.0841],[7.6993,99.0833],[7.7013,99.0827],[7.7028,99.0826],[7.7029,99.0825],[7.7035,99.0818],[7.7041,99.0819],[7.7042,99.0818],[7.7043,99.0817],[7.7046,99.0809],[7.7039,99.0809],[7.7029,99.0813],[7.7028,99.079],[7.7033,99.0786],[7.7034,99.0785],[7.704,99.0784],[7.7043,99.0783],[7.7048,99.0782],[7.7051,99.0771],[7.7054,99.077],[7.7061,99.0768],[7.7067,99.0768],[7.7071,99.0769],[7.7074,99.0769],[7.7076,99.0769],[7.7079,99.0758],[7.7081,99.0757],[7.7098,99.0748],[7.7098,99.0739],[7.7088,99.0736],[7.7087,99.0737],[7.7081,99.0738],[7.7069,99.0726],[7.7094,99.07],[7.7092,99.0679],[7.7103,99.0666],[7.7114,99.0649],[7.7126,99.063],[7.7136,99.0623],[7.7146,99.0619],[7.7143,99.061],[7.7152,99.0599],[7.7178,99.0568],[7.7179,99.0559],[7.7231,99.0533],[7.7253,99.0527],[7.7268,99.0531],[7.727,99.0533],[7.7257,99.0558],[7.7241,99.0562],[7.7236,99.0567],[7.7234,99.057],[7.7221,99.0579],[7.7211,99.0595],[7.7218,99.0601],[7.722,99.0602],[7.7223,99.0601],[7.7224,99.0601],[7.7226,99.0601],[7.7229,99.06],[7.7245,99.0615],[7.7251,99.0618],[7.7257,99.0621],[7.7264,99.0626],[7.726,99.0641],[7.7259,99.0642],[7.7245,99.0646],[7.7243,99.0646],[7.724,99.0646],[7.7226,99.0641],[7.721,99.0649],[7.7208,99.0656],[7.7202,99.0662],[7.7212,99.066],[7.721,99.0667],[7.7229,99.0668],[7.7231,99.0669],[7.7234,99.067],[7.7241,99.0678],[7.7244,99.0679],[7.7257,99.0677],[7.7268,99.0676],[7.7285,99.0678],[7.7311,99.0683],[7.732,99.0692],[7.7322,99.0693],[7.7326,99.0693],[7.7327,99.0692],[7.7327,99.069],[7.7325,99.0688],[7.7321,99.0684],[7.7326,99.068],[7.7327,99.0678],[7.7326,99.0676],[7.7324,99.0675],[7.7324,99.0672],[7.7327,99.0662],[7.7339,99.0655],[7.7348,99.0631],[7.7358,99.0629],[7.7376,99.0622],[7.7387,99.0623],[7.7404,99.0661],[7.7404,99.0677],[7.7416,99.0684],[7.7427,99.0681],[7.743,99.0681],[7.745,99.0683],[7.7458,99.0674],[7.7462,99.0671],[7.747,99.0666],[7.7481,99.0669],[7.7486,99.0672],[7.7491,99.0678],[7.7495,99.0692],[7.7496,99.0693],[7.7501,99.0694],[7.7508,99.0693],[7.7518,99.0697],[7.7542,99.07],[7.7549,99.0698],[7.7556,99.0702],[7.7553,99.0688],[7.7563,99.0677],[7.7577,99.0673],[7.7581,99.0662],[7.7582,99.0652],[7.7589,99.0656],[7.759,99.0664],[7.7617,99.0648],[7.7618,99.0648],[7.7634,99.0655],[7.7644,99.0656],[7.7653,99.0648],[7.7653,99.0647],[7.7667,99.0641],[7.7682,99.0635],[7.7699,99.063],[7.7704,99.0628],[7.7714,99.0633],[7.7717,99.0634],[7.7719,99.0633],[7.772,99.0633],[7.7726,99.063],[7.7732,99.0629],[7.7735,99.0629],[7.7737,99.063],[7.7739,99.063],[7.7742,99.0632],[7.7746,99.0634],[7.7748,99.0635],[7.7749,99.0635],[7.7752,99.0635],[7.7754,99.0635],[7.7755,99.0635],[7.7757,99.0635],[7.776,99.0637],[7.7765,99.064],[7.7766,99.064],[7.7769,99.0641],[7.7774,99.0638],[7.7775,99.0638],[7.7777,99.0638],[7.7777,99.0638],[7.7779,99.0638],[7.7781,99.0638],[7.7783,99.0638],[7.7786,99.0638],[7.7788,99.0637],[7.78,99.0632]]]}}]}
```

Either way, it looks like your projection/coordinate system is not WGS84:

[image]

I mean, your geojson is now valid but most certainly not what you actually drew. So before you export from QGIS, make sure you select the correct coordinate system. 5sec of googling: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/35595 or http://jonathansoma.com/tutorials/mapping/change-crs-with-qgis/